# Meaning of this notion in 0-1 loss?

Tags: machine-learning, loss-function, mathematics

I am reading [a paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5073-learning-with-noisy-labels.pdf) and encountered this notion:

$$1_{\{Y=1\}}$$

To me it seems to be the expression as below, but I am not entirely sure and I don't think the author explictly explained it:

```
if Y==1:
  return 1
else:
  return 0
```

Can someone help me to clarify this notion? Much thanks for your time (:

---

It appears in:

https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5073-learning-with-noisy-labels.pdf

[image: weighted 0-1 loss]

Comment: Your assumption is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.

This is known as the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).

The indicator function of a subset $A$ of a set $X$ is a function

$$1_A(x)= \begin{cases}1, & x \in A \\ 0, & x \notin A \end{cases}$$

Comment: Also since both $I_{\{Y=1\}}$ and $I_{\{y=1\}}$ are present in the question. It is worth noting that $Z=I_{\{Y=1\}}$ is a random variable like $Z=2Y$ with a distribution, unlike $f(y)=I_{\{y=1\}}$ which is a function with no distribution.